# Как исправить "Нет такого файла или каталога" в Linux?

Tags: linux, archlinux

При запуске любой Linux программы из shell получаем ошибку вида:
`bash: /usr/bin/wine: Нет такого файла или каталога`
Переменные окружения PATH выставлены корректно и сам файл существует.

Comment: Проверьте ассоциации mime types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл ld-linux.so.2(ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 для 64 битной архитекруры) пуст или поврежден. Исправляется заменой его на рабочий из резервной копии.

Comment: Это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Ответ

Comment: в таком случае, он  не отвечает на вопрос "как исправить".

Comment: А как система умудрилась загрузиться?

Comment: strace ваш лучший друг и ldd товарищ